# selected only one value dropdown on custom dropdown Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown, ngfor

I using my own custom dropdown which I need to using selected only one value , it supposed to be when I clicked `Dropdown1`, `div` will displayed `Dropdown1`, when I clicked `Dropdown2` it will replaced Dropdown1 in `div`. this is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frxvgg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) link I created,

**ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  savedCards = [];
  show = false;
  hasSelected: boolean;

    savedCreditCards = [
    { id: '001', viewValue: 'Dropdown1' },
    { id: '002', viewValue: 'Dropdown2' },
    { id: '003', viewValue: 'Dropdown3' },
    { id: '004', viewValue: 'Dropdown4' },
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  selectSavedCard() {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }

  selectDropdownCard(card) {
    this.savedCards.find((item) => item.id === card.id) ?
      this.savedCards = this.savedCards.filter((item) => item.id === card.id) :
      this.savedCards.push(card);
    this.show = false;
    this.hasSelected = true;
  }

}
```

**html**

```
  <div class="div1" (click)="selectSavedCard()">
    <div *ngIf='!hasSelected'>
      <div>
        <p>dropdown</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let card of savedCards">
      <div>
        <p>{{card.viewValue}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div2" *ngIf="show">
    <div *ngFor="let card of savedCreditCards" (click)="selectDropdownCard(card)">
      <div>
        <p>{{card.viewValue}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I know it can be done with set `savedCards` array as empty but I believe it not the best practice, Need opinion and suggestion,

Comment: if you want only one selected options then why is savedCards an array?

Comment: because I need to iterate *ngFor on html

Comment: but to show all the options in the dropdown you are using the other array

Comment: if I set savedCards a string, how do I filter card.id, also I had try to make it a string, it didnt work

Comment: just make it an object to store the only one saved card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show only single card which was selected, instead of pushing it into array. Just create a new array with single item. Which means in your `selectDropdownCard` method

replace this `this.savedCards.push(card);` with `this.savedCards = [card];`

Comment: I see, I didnt realised that I push an array, this should be acceptable answer

Answer (score 0):

You are using an array to store something that should have only a single value.
You should define savedCard as a simple object, remove the ng-for used to cicle through the savedCards in the html and save just the clicked card.

I updated your example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdipzb)